# state_machine can't delete record in initial state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I tried different models now, and I always get the same result.

```
model Foo
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :title, String

  attr_accessible :title


  state_machine :state, :initial => :new do

    state :new
    state :faa

    event :faa do
      transition :new => :faa
    end

  end
end
```

in rails console:

```
bar = Foo.new
bar.state
=> "new"

bar.title = "something"
=> "something"

bar.valid?
=> true
bar.destroy
=> nil

bar.foo
bar.state
=> "faa"
bar.destroy
=> true
```

Any idea, why I am not able to delete the object in the database? I tried the log, but unfortunately it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state should not be named `new`, because it is a reserved Ruby word. Change this status to i.e. `initial`, it should help.